# Same jar when signing, different md5 after signing

Tags: jar, md5, hash, checksum

why the md5 checksum always change when i sign the file? I have the same jar file before sign it, but if I sign it twice the md5 checksum of the two signed jars are different. My question is why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because signing the file injects a signature, which changes the contents of the file.  Changing the contents of a file will of course change the digest.

Comment: i believe that the file that is changed is the .DSA (digital signature algorithm) which contains the digital signature.

Comment: Is this file being embedded in the .jar?  If so, that would explain why the digest is changing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the signing procedure, however for security reasons signing of documents occur with random (say 256 bit) data. Otherwise it would be a handicap.

Answer (score 0):

good day. 
it because your hash created form not only of constant data. 
this hashing method called `salt`(entropy).

for instance:

> > md5(name + salt)

salt may be time or any none constant data

[entropy](https://www.google.ru/#hl=ru&newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=wiki+entropy+cryptography&oq=wiki+entropy+cr&aq=0KL&aqi=g-KL1g-bKL1&aql=&gs_l=hp.3.0.0i30i19j0i8i30i19.23643.24502.21.25852.3.3.0.0.0.0.479.751.0j2j4-1.4.0...0.0.J-iVVFnhw2A&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=39938a686955499f&biw=1115&bih=619)